# 400 bad request [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]

Tags: java, json, rest, http-post, special-characters

I am trying to call an api. Whenever i include 'é' in the request body getting 400 bad request. When i remvove 'é' everything works fine. below is my code and response.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = (CloseableHttpClient) getHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = getHttpPost("xxx");
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(request.toString());
            entity.setChunked(false);
            httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            System.out.println("contentlength = "+String.valueOf(entity.getContentLength()));
            CloseableHttpResponse response = (CloseableHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           System.out.println("response = "
                + response);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
           System.out.println("statusLine = "
                + statusLine);

            String responseEntity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
           System.out.println("responseEntity = "
                + responseEntity);
```

Response :

> contentlength = 964 response = HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad
>   Request [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]} statusLine = HTTP/1.1 400
>   Bad Request responseEntity =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(request.toString(),"UTF-8");
```

this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set the content-type to:

```
"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

when sending the post request in the application you are using.

Comment: Tried. but no luck.